Why is the code coverage in my Apex class not calculating properly?
I build a custom UI using LWC. The LWC allows you to , run the selected tests,

select which tests you would like to run together
run the selected tests
gets the code coverage of each test and averages them together.
and records the information on a custom object.

All of the above is working accept the linesCovered, linesUncovered are all 0. The tests that I'm running are all over 80% when ran in the developer console. I believe there is either something wrong with how I'm calculating the code coverage, or the json is not deserializing properly.
I used several debug logs in my Apex and error handling in my code and got back these results:
08:46:17:582 USER_DEBUG [198]|DEBUG|Coverage Data - Name: NAICSCodeUpdateTest, Covered: 0, Uncovered: 0, Percent: 0.0 
08:46:17:583 USER_DEBUG [111]|DEBUG|Fetched coverage results: (CoverageData:[className=NAICSCodeUpdateTest, coveragePercentage=0.0, numLinesCovered=0, numLinesUncovered=0]) 08:46:17:583 USER_DEBUG [130]|DEBUG|Calculated total coverage: 0.0 
08:46:17:617 USER_DEBUG [136]|DEBUG|Updated Test_Result__c with Coverage_Percent__c: Test_Result__c:{Id=a0EVZ000000FLfF2AW, JobId__c=1721738754256, TestClassIds__c=["01p7h000002RSlbAAG"], Coverage_Percent__c=0.0}

  @RestResource(urlmapping='/TestResultsController2')
  global with sharing class TestResultsController2 {

public class CoverageData {
    @AuraEnabled public String className { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public Integer numLinesCovered { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public Integer numLinesUncovered { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public Double coveragePercentage { get; set; }

    public CoverageData(String className, Integer numLinesCovered, Integer numLinesUncovered, Double coveragePercentage) {
        this.className = className;
        this.numLinesCovered = numLinesCovered;
        this.numLinesUncovered = numLinesUncovered;
        this.coveragePercentage = coveragePercentage;
    }
}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
global static List<ApexClass> getTestClasses() {
    String searchTerm = '%Test%'; 
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM ApexClass WHERE NamespacePrefix = null AND (Name LIKE :searchTerm OR Name LIKE :('%' + searchTerm))];
}

@HttpPost
@AuraEnabled
global static String runTests(List<String> selectedTestIds) {
    List<ApexTestQueueItem> queueItems = new List<ApexTestQueueItem>();
    List<ApexClass> selectedTestClasses = [SELECT Id, Name FROM ApexClass WHERE Id IN :selectedTestIds];
    
    for (ApexClass cls : selectedTestClasses) {
        queueItems.add(new ApexTestQueueItem(ApexClassId = cls.Id));
    }
    insert queueItems;

    // Return a unique job ID to track the test run
    String jobId = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Test_Result__c job = new Test_Result__c(JobId__c = jobId, TestClassIds__c = JSON.serialize(selectedTestIds));
    insert job;

    return jobId;
}

@AuraEnabled
global static Map<String, Object> getTestResults(String jobId) {
    System.debug('Entering getTestResults with jobId: ' + jobId);
    
    Test_Result__c job;
    try {
        job = [SELECT Id, JobId__c, TestClassIds__c FROM Test_Result__c WHERE JobId__c = :jobId LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('Fetched Test_Result__c record: ' + job);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('Exception querying Test_Result__c: ' + e.getMessage());
        return new Map<String, Object>{
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Error querying job record: ' + e.getMessage()
        };
    }
    List<String> testClassIds = new List<String>();
    try {
        String decodedTestClassIds = decodeHtml(job.TestClassIds__c);
        System.debug('Decoded test class IDs: ' + decodedTestClassIds);
        List<Object> parsedIds = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(decodedTestClassIds);
        for (Object obj : parsedIds) {
            testClassIds.add(String.valueOf(obj));
        }
        System.debug('Deserialized test class IDs: ' + testClassIds);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('Exception deserializing TestClassIds__c: ' + e.getMessage());
        return new Map<String, Object>{
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Error deserializing test class IDs: ' + e.getMessage()
        };
    }

    // Check if all tests have completed
    List<ApexTestQueueItem> queueItems;
    try {
        queueItems = [SELECT Id, Status FROM ApexTestQueueItem WHERE ApexClassId IN :testClassIds];
        System.debug('Fetched ApexTestQueueItem records: ' + queueItems);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('Exception querying ApexTestQueueItem: ' + e.getMessage());
        return new Map<String, Object>{
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Error querying test queue items: ' + e.getMessage()
        };
    }

    Boolean allCompleted = true;
    for (ApexTestQueueItem item : queueItems) {
        System.debug('TestQueueItem status: ' + item.Status);
        if (item.Status != 'Completed') {
            allCompleted = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!allCompleted) {
        System.debug('Tests are still running for jobId: ' + jobId);
        return new Map<String, Object>{
            'status' => 'InProgress',
            'message' => 'Tests are still running'
        };
    }

    System.debug('All tests completed for jobId: ' + jobId + '. Fetching coverage results.');

    // Fetch code coverage results using Tooling API
    List<CoverageData> coverageList;
    try {
        coverageList = fetchCodeCoverage(testClassIds);
        System.debug('Fetched coverage results: ' + coverageList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('Exception fetching code coverage: ' + e.getMessage());
        return new Map<String, Object>{
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Error fetching code coverage: ' + e.getMessage()
        };
    }

    // Calculate the overall coverage percentage
    Double totalCoverage = 0;
    if (!coverageList.isEmpty()) {
        Double sumOfCoveragePercentages = 0;
        for (CoverageData data : coverageList) {
            sumOfCoveragePercentages += data.coveragePercentage;
        }
        totalCoverage = sumOfCoveragePercentages / coverageList.size();
    }

    System.debug('Calculated total coverage: ' + totalCoverage);

    // Update the Test_Result__c record with the coverage percentage
    try {
        job.Coverage_Percent__c = totalCoverage;
        update job;
        System.debug('Updated Test_Result__c with Coverage_Percent__c: ' + job);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('Exception updating Coverage_Percent__c: ' + e.getMessage());
        return new Map<String, Object>{
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Error updating job record: ' + e.getMessage()
        };
    }

    Map<String, Object> result = new Map<String, Object>();
    result.put('status', 'Completed');
    result.put('coverageData', coverageList);
    result.put('coveragePercentage', totalCoverage);

    return result;
}

@AuraEnabled
global static void cleanUpJob(String jobId) {
    // Clean up the job record after completion
    delete [SELECT Id FROM Test_Result__c WHERE JobId__c = :jobId];
}

private static List<CoverageData> fetchCodeCoverage(List<String> testClassIds) {
    String query = 'SELECT ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered ' +
                   'FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate ' +
                   'WHERE ApexClassOrTriggerId IN (\'' + String.join(testClassIds, '\',\'') + '\') ' +
                   'ORDER BY ApexClassOrTrigger.Name ASC';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('callout:SalesforceAPI/services/data/v53.0/tooling/query/?q=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query, 'UTF-8'));
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');

    System.debug('Tooling API request endpoint: ' + req.getEndpoint());
    System.debug('Tooling API request query: ' + query);

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res;

    try {
        res = http.send(req);
        System.debug('Tooling API callout response status: ' + res.getStatus());
        System.debug('Tooling API callout response body: ' + res.getBody());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('Tooling API callout exception: ' + e.getMessage());
        throw new CalloutException('Failed to fetch code coverage data: ' + e.getMessage());
    }

    List<CoverageData> coverageList = new List<CoverageData>();

    if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        try {
            testCoverageWrapper tcw = (testCoverageWrapper) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), testCoverageWrapper.class);
            System.debug('Deserialized testCoverageWrapper: ' + tcw);
            for (testCoverageWrapper.records record : tcw.records) {
                System.debug('Processing record: ' + record);
                String name = record.ApexClassOrTrigger.Name;
                Integer numLinesCovered = record.NumLinesCovered;
                Integer numLinesUncovered = record.NumLinesUncovered;
                Integer totalLines = numLinesCovered + numLinesUncovered;
                Double coveragePercent = (totalLines > 0) ? ((Double)numLinesCovered / totalLines) * 100 : 0;
                System.debug('Coverage Data - Name: ' + name + ', Covered: ' + numLinesCovered + ', Uncovered: ' + numLinesUncovered + ', Percent: ' + coveragePercent);
                coverageList.add(new CoverageData(name, numLinesCovered, numLinesUncovered, coveragePercent));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception deserializing JSON response: ' + e.getMessage());
            System.debug('Response body: ' + res.getBody());
            throw new CalloutException('Failed to deserialize code coverage data: ' +  e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        System.debug('Error from Tooling API: ' + res.getBody());
        throw new CalloutException('Tooling API call failed with status: ' + res.getStatus());
    }

    return coverageList;
}

private static String decodeHtml(String input) {
    input = input.replace('&quot;', '"');
    input = input.replace('&amp;', '&');
    input = input.replace('&lt;', '<');
    input = input.replace('&gt;', '>');
    input.replace('&#39;', '\'');
    return input;
}
}

